# Python recursion function

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, recursion, radix

I am trying to take a number, do floor division on it, until it becomes 0. This must be done using recursion with a base case.
For example:

```
>>>Base(5,2)
2 ##(5//2)
1 ##(2//2)
0 ##(1//2)
```

This is what I have so far:

```
def Base(number,base):
    result=1
    if result==0:
        return False
    else:
        result=number//base
        return Base(result,base)
```

Comment: You have two problems. You are setting your result to 1 all the time and you have a `n` that has never been declared.

Comment: @idjaw I changed n. Sorry I mean number there.

Comment: Great. Now take care of `result=1` at the beginning of your function. Think about what is happening when you keep setting `result=1`. Run through it line by line.

Comment: @idjaw That's a good point. How should I declare result since I can't set it to a specific number?

Comment: How about `number = number // base` :)

Comment: @idjaw That would not be a recursion, wouldn't it?

Comment: What is your definition of recursion? Why would that not be recursive?

Comment: @idjaw Okay, I got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
def Base(number,base):

        if number==0:
            return False
        else:
            number = number//base
            print(number)
            return Base(number,base)
```

First of all using result = 1 should be removed as during every recursive call result will be reinitialized to 1 and the following if statement will never work. 
What you needed to do was to keep on dividing the number recursively till it reaches 0 and print False

I hope it clears your doubt